# Android device A101T not listed in "Available Devices" when publishing app

Tags: google-play, android, archos

I've published an app for Android 2.2+. Android Market says it's supported by over 968 devices. Now a customer says he can't install the app. Android Market gives him this error message:

*"Your device isn't compatible with this item."*

So I checked if his "Archos 101 Internet Tablet (**A101T**)" (Firmware 2.4.82, Android 2.2.1, not rooted) was accidently excluded. From what I can see, this device is not even listed when clicking "Device Availability" in the Developer Console. When I search for Archos devices, I get the following list:

- ARCHOS 101G9(A101)
- ARCHOS 70it2(A70it2)
- ARCHOS 80G9(A80)
- ARCHOS 80G9(A80S)
- Archos 101 Internet Tablet(A101S)

No A101T!

**Q:** Why isn't this device even listed? How can I make my app work on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't this device even listed?

Because that device model does not have the Android Market on it. It does not pass the CTS and does not ship from ARCHOS with the Android Market.

Comment: Thanks. So how can I make my app installable on it?

Comment: @NOPslider: You can try distributing it by some means other than the Android Market, such as ARCHOS' own AppsLib. Why you are trying to support a known software pirate (your "customer" pirated the Android Market app, by his own admission) is beyond me.

Comment: Just an FYI, you *CAN* get your app to work on these devices by disabling copy protection in the developer console.  I ran across the same problem with the same device mentioned above.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158710/android-app-not-compatible-with-devices-that-sideload-google-play